# how to get the value of a http request response in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, console

Actually what I wants to know is how to get the value of the name in Vuejsof a http request.Please see the image for the Chrome console [click here to see the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuWr0.png)
to get the value of name i have written below code at Register.vue .But after user registration it shows under application tab of chrome name is undefined.

```
 .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      let accessToken = response.data.access_token
      localStorage.setItem('token', accessToken)
      localStorage.setItem('user', response.config.data.name)
```

So could anyone please tell me how to get the value of name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response.config.data is a String (see the double qoutes). You need to parse it (JSON.parse) and then you can take the name property.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You could provide a short piece of code to illustrate how to parse the String :)

Comment: if you could please provide the code or tell me where should i edit please

Comment: `/* change the last line of your code into these */
const configData = JSON.parse(response.config.data);
localStorage.setItem('user', configData.name);`